# Locale of database session

Tags: azure-synapse

I need to be able to alert users to exceptions (e.g., long-running queries) on Azure SQL Data Warehouse (ADW).

In reviewing sys.dm_pdw_exec_sessions (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt203883.aspx) I don't see any context information that would indicate the timezone the user is located in.

If I give the user a notice referencing UTC time, they will inevitably be confused.  Can applications connecting to ADW specify user context including their client's timezone?  Does ADW log such?

Answer (score 0):

SQL DW does not support session based time offsets.
For the scenario that you want to solve could you build it in the presentation layer?